# Python FFmpeg: Single static image coupled with audio outputs massive file size

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm using [this Python library](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) to programmatically generate a video using a single static image (.PNG - 3.05 MB - 1920 x 1080) and an audio track (.WAV - pcm_s24le (24 bit) - 48000 Hz - 34.6 MB) as input.

I'm using [this technique](https://superuser.com/a/1417596) to speed up the video generation process.

However, the final file size of `output_video_final` is 2.33 GB. Considering my input file sizes (.PNG - 3.05 MB / .WAV - 34.6 MB), why is the final .MOV output so large?

Here's my code:

```
    '''
    Generate .MOV using static image as input
    '''
    image = ffmpeg.input(input_image, loop='1', t='00:00:1', framerate='24000/1001', probesize='42M')

    output = ffmpeg.output(image, output_video,
    f='mov',
    vcodec='prores_ks',
    vprofile='3',
    pix_fmt='yuv422p10le',
    g='120',
    video_track_timescale='24000',
    movflags='use_metadata_tags',
    timecode='00:00:00:00',
    color_primaries='bt709',
    color_trc='bt709',
    colorspace='bt709',
    qcomp='1',
    preset='veryfast',
    bsf='prores_metadata=color_primaries=bt709:color_trc=bt709:colorspace=bt709',   
    vf='scale=in_range=full:in_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=full:out_color_matrix=bt709')

    output.run()

    '''
    Generate .MOV using static image .MOV in previous output
    and combine with audio input
    '''
    audio = ffmpeg.input(input_audio, filter_complex='channelsplit')
    video = ffmpeg.input(output_video, t='00:02:06', stream_loop='126')

    output = ffmpeg.output(video, audio, output_video_final,
    vcodec='copy',
    acodec='pcm_s24le',
    audio_bitrate=bitrate)

    output.run()
```

Comment: did you try to use `mp4` or `avi` instead of `mov` ?

Comment: did you try to compres only audio? Maybe problem is audio.

Comment: @furas unfortunately this is a post-production media output that needs to adhere to these specs so I can't use `mp4` or `avi`. Thanks

Comment: @furas I cannot compress the audio. The output needs to remain the same as the input (excluding the channel split). FYI the audio specs are pcm_s24le (24 bit), 48000 Hz.

Comment: if you don't want to chage audio then maybe you should use `acode=copy`. But you could use `ffmpeg to create new file only with audio to see it will be bigger then before and if audio can makes so big file.

Answer (score 1):

Your original input is a single image, however your output is a video stream 2m 6s long as per `t='00:02:06'` at 23.976 fps. So, that's around 3020 Full HD frames, each compressed independently, using a ProRes encoder at profile HQ. ProRes is a mezzanine codec meant for post-production workflows, where the priority is maintaining quality, not an economical file size.

If the audio input is already 24 bits, then it will take roughly the same size inside the MOV, even accounting for the channelsplit.

Comment: As mentioned in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340228/python-ffmpeg-single-static-image-coupled-with-audio-outputs-massive-file-size/59341533#comment104883024_59340228), the output is meant for a post-production workflow that is required to adhere exactly to the specified specs. The audio specs are pcm_s24le (24 bit), 48000 Hz - and again, they have to remain that way during the output. Is it a requirement to encode each frame independently using this encoder? It seems odd considering it's a static image throughout the entire playback.

Comment: ProRes is an intra-frame codec. It doesn't know or care whether the current frame is identical to the previous one. Each frame is meant to be compressed standalone.

Comment: Understood. Knowing that, are there any methods to make each frame compression more efficient to reduce the file size, even minimally? Edit: without altering the vcodec, vprofile and pix_fmt. Thanks

Comment: Could I also ask, what would be the recommended GOP (set via `g`) for 23.976 content? Thanks

Comment: No, prores has very limited options for tuning compression. `-g` has no relevance for intra-frame codecs since all frames are independent.